# why cannot I capture VScode window when I press PrtSc button or win+shift+s

Tags: visual-studio-code, screen-capture

why cannot I capture VScode window when I press PrtSc button or win+shift+s

OS:windows10  Ver:20H,internal 19042.1415
VScode v1.63.2(Nov 2021)

before I press button, my screen is fulled by vscode;
when I press down,vscode disappears automatically, nothing but wallpaper;
then I press up,vscode come back automatically!

Comment: Is this vscode specific or does any other program do this too?

Comment: only vscode, but it can be captured normally a month ago. Now I install vscode the same version in several win10 v19042 PCs, end the same

Comment: Hm, weird, to be honest, I have absolutelly no idea why this happens, and I am unable to replicate it with same PC specs

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is this issue happening when you use snipping tool also?

Comment: re: yeah, all the same, such as faststone capture, wechat (alt +a), win10 snip&sketch (win+shift+s)...